# Numpad not working in VIM on Windows

Tags: windows, vim, command-prompt, numpad

I'm using VIM on windows(the command line app from the basic command prompt) and when I press any number key on the numpad it inserts a 'Î' character, it also happens if I press shift+arrow keys. How can I make the numpad insert the actual numbers instead? It is really annoying as I'm using an AZERTY keyboard so to insert numbers I have to press shift+key if I use the number row and not numpad

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7274961/2415524